# adb 1.0.31 fails to detect device

Tags: adb, usb, usb-debugging, xiaomi, xiaomi-mi4

I noticed a strange behaviour. I am fixing different bug, so I am trying different version of `adb` one by one on my phone.

I tried `1.0.26`, `1.0.29`, `1.0.31`, `1.0.32`, `1.0.36`, all except for `1.0.31` are able to detect my device.

my phone is 
`MI4LTE`

Android 
`6.0.1 MMB29M`

and I am using MIUI
`MIUI 8.1 | Stable 8.1.3.0(MXDCNDI)`

Anyone has an idea what could possibly cuase that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by phone not set in USB charging mode in settings

`Settings > Additional settings > Developer options > Select USB Configurations > Charging only`

This made `1.0.31` behave just like remaining versions of ADB mentioned in the question.